# No se controló InvalidCatchException

Tags: c#

[image: Cuando ingreso un cliente , lo ingresa bien pero luego cuando voy a escribir la matricula del vehículo para buscarlo me salta este error]

Cuando ingreso un cliente , lo ingresa bien pero luego cuando voy a escribir la matricula del vehículo para buscarlo me salta este error

```
Declaracion lista:
class Empresa
{
    string cedula;
    string matricula;
    ArrayList lista;

    public Empresa()
    {
        cedula = "No tiene";
        matricula = "Sin Matricula";
        lista = new ArrayList();
    }
```

Comment: El error es muy descriptivo. `lista[i]` contiene un objeto de tipo `Clientes`, no de tipo `Vehiculos`.En `lista` puede haber objetos de ambos tipos?

Comment: Supongo que si , vos decis que no se pueden llamar i los dos

Comment: No he dicho eso, pero debes mirar primero que tipo de objeto es antes de intentar convertirlo. Mira mi respuesta.

Comment: Francop incluye en tu código la decalracón de `lista`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Si en `lista` los objetos pueden ser de tipo `Clientes` y de tipo `Vehiculos`, tienes que controlar el tipo del objeto antes de intentar hacer el cast. Puedes hacerlo de varias formas:

```
Vehiculos v=null;
for (int i=0;i<lista.Count;i++)
{
    if (lista[i] is Vehiculos)
    {
        if (((Vehiculos)lista[i]).Matricula == mat)
        {
             v=(Vehiculos)lista[i];
             //i=lista.Count
             break;
        }
    }
    return v;
}
```

Verás que he comentado una linea de tu código. Es muy peligroso modificar una variable de indexación de un bucle dentro de el. Si lo que quieres es no seguir buscando, usa `break;` para salir del bucle.

Hay otra manera que puedes usar para lo mismo, usando Linq y en una sola línea:

```
Vehiculo v=lista.OfType<Vehiculos>().Where(x=>x.Matricula==mat).FirstOrDefault();
```

Comment: me sirvi la primera , la segunda aun no la conozco , muchas gracias por la ayuda!

Comment: una pregunta, cuando tendo eso mismo que pase pero en Clientes debo hacer lo mismo pero castear vehiculos? porque sino me va a tirar ese error pero en clientes

Comment: perdon castear clientes

Comment: En principio,así es.De todas maneras,como te comentó @CarlosMuñoz, deberías poner la definición de `lista` que imagino es de alguna clase base de `Clientes`y `Vehiculos`. A mi lo que me parece es que tienes algun problema de diseño, ya que no es muy lógico que tengas una lista con objetos de ambos tipos, aunque sin ver más codigo es dificil decirlo.

Comment: Ahi lo agregue, el codigo que pase anteriormente esta incluido en la clase empresa, clientes y vehiculos son clases bases que estan asociados con empresa

Comment: ahi mande el codigo, corrobore que todo funcione y funciona!